# Wait for GUI to finish - MATLAB

Tags: user-interface, matlab

I am running a program, in the end I ran a GUI that writes responses to an Excel file. In the contium of the program I try to read these files. It seem to me that MATLAB tries to read before the files are created by the GUI.

How can I tell the program to wait until the GUI is finished (button is pressed)?

Something like:

```
>>Run_Gui()
>>WaitSomeh ow()
>>xlsread(...)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to wait until a figure is closed, try using

```
f = figure();
uiwait(f);
```

As @stefangretar suggested correctly, you can use

```
uiresume(f)
```

If you don't want to destroy the window.

Comment: and uiresume [uiwait](http://www.mathworks.se/help/techdoc/ref/uiwait.html) [uiresume](http://www.mathworks.se/help/techdoc/ref/uiresume.html)