# How do I pause execution in Matlab, but allow Copy\Paste via the keyboard

Tags: c#, wpf, matlab

My question is similar to this:
[Wait for gui to finish - matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8636475/wait-for-gui-to-finish-matlab)

But, the `uiwait(f)` doesn't work - when the user hits <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> - it closes the app rather than doing a copy.

Here's the situation:

We're compiling MATLAB, and running WPF on top to provide the UI. However, we need to block the MATLAB execution in order to display our WPF UI. In the past we've used the `input()` command - but this causes severe CPU load.

Using `waitfor` or `uiwait` is better, but again, prevents our users from using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> in the WPF UI. No Good!

Anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: Can I see some code? Because WPF style this is very easy to achieve, while the Matlab way is pretty tricky... but I don't know how your implementation look like.

Answer (score 0):

You have to stop the processing, not the UI.

Often stopping the UI will stop the processing as a side effect (the Process is waiting for the UI to accept a write order or something). But it will also stop any input processing, like Ctrl+C.

Google says there should be a "pause" command of some sort to do this:

- https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/68698-can-i-pause-matlab-excution-while-it-is-already-running
- [Stop and continue execution from debugger possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272541/stop-and-continue-execution-from-debugger-possible)